# Segmentation fault / Incorrect checksum triggered ocasionally when reading lines from a file

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to implement a function that gets every line from a file and prints it. For some reason, when running it I get a segmentation fault sometimes, sometimes it just runs fine, sometimes it exits with a incorrect checksum for freed object. I don't know which pointer is not being freed/modified after freeing it, can I get some clue?

The variable **BUFFER_SIZE** is defined from the keyboard, where I compile with the flags **gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -D BUFFER_SIZE=23 get_next_line.c main.c**

```c
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>

    char    *ft_strjoin(char const *s1, char const *s2)
    {
        char    *s;
        int     p;
        int     p2;
    
        if (s1 == NULL || s2 == NULL)
            return (NULL);
        s = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
        if (s == NULL)
            return (NULL);
        p = 0;
        while (s1[p])
        {
            s[p] = s1[p];
            p++;
        }
        p2 = 0;
        while (s2[p2])
        {
            s[p] = s2[p2];
            p++;
            p2++;
        }
        s[p] = '\0';
        return (s);
    }

    char    *ft_newstatic(char *aux, char *l, char **line)
    {
        char    *temp;
        int     leng;
    
        leng = strlen(l);
        temp = malloc(leng + 1);
        strlcat(temp, l, strlen(temp) + (leng - strlen(aux)) + 1);
        *line = strdup(temp);
        free(temp);
        l = NULL;
        l = strdup(&aux[1]);
        return (l);
    }
    
    int     get_next_line(int fd, char **line)
    {
        static char *stc_line;
        char        *buffer;
        ssize_t     nbytes;
        char        *aux;
    
        stc_line = (!stc_line) ? strdup("") : stc_line;
        buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE + 1);
        if (!buffer || fd <= 0 || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0 || !line)
            return (-1);
        while ((nbytes = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
        {
            buffer[nbytes] = '\0';
            stc_line = ft_strjoin(stc_line, buffer);
            if ((aux = strchr(stc_line, '\n')) != NULL)
            {
                //free(buffer);
                return (((stc_line = ft_newstatic(aux, stc_line, line)) != NULL) ? 1 : 1);
            }
        }
        if (nbytes < 0)
            return (-1);
        if ((aux = strchr(stc_line, '\n')) != NULL)
        {
            //free(buffer);
            return (((stc_line = ft_newstatic(aux, stc_line, line)) != NULL) ? 1 : 1);
        }
        *line = strdup(stc_line);
        stc_line = NULL;
        free(buffer);
        return (0);
    }
```

If I remove both free(buffer) before returning ft_newstatic I get better results (less running time and not as many seg faults), but if I remove

```
stc_line = NULL;
free(stc_line);
```

I get weird output again:

> 2- archivo: texto.txt
>
> [Return: 1] Line #124458: En un lugar de la mancha
>
> [Return: 1] Line #124459: de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme
>
> [Return: 1] Line #124460: habia un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero
>
> [Return: 1] Line #124461: adarga antigua
>
> [Return: 1] Line #124462: rocín flaco
>
> [Return: 0] Line #124463: y galgo corredor.
>
> End of file
>
> 3- archivo: texto2.txt
>
> [Return: 1] Line #124464: y galgo corredor.linea 1
>
> [Return: 1] Line #124465: linea 2
>
> [Return: 1] Line #124466: linea 3
>
> [Return: 0] Line #124467: linea 4
>
> End of file

This is the main() that I use

```c
    #include <sys/types.h>
    
    int get_next_line(int fd, char **line);
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        int fd;
        int ret;
        int line;
        char *buff;
        int     i;
    
        line = 0;
        if (argc > 1)
        {
            i = 0;
            while (++i < argc)
            {
                fd = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
                printf("%d- archivo: %s\n",i, argv[i]);
                while ((ret = get_next_line(fd, &buff)) > 0)
                {
                    printf("[Return: %d] Line #%d: %s\n", ret, ++line, buff);
                    free(buff);
                }
                printf("[Return: %d] Line #%d: %s\n", ret, ++line, buff);
                if (ret == -1)
                    printf("-----------\nError\n");
                else if (ret == 0)
                    printf("-----------\nEnd of file\n");
                free(buff);
            }
        }
        if (argc == 1)
        {
            while ((ret = get_next_line(0, &buff)) > 0)
                printf("[Return: %d] Line #%d: %s\n", ret, ++line, buff);
            if (ret == -1)
                printf("-----------\nError\n");
            else if (ret == 0)
                printf("-----------\nEnd of stdin\n");
            free(buff);
            close(fd);
        }
        return (0);
    }
```

Comment: Check for buffer overflows.

Comment: Also show a [mcve].

Comment: Are you certain the strings are null-terminated? If they aren't, then those string functions can access past the end of valid memory. You should be able to step through with your debugger to confirm this.

Comment: Pretty sure strings are null-terminated, strlcat ends strings with '\0', strdup too, and as you can see strjoin too.

Comment: This looks wrong:
 `l = NULL; free(l);`

Comment: @hko

I know, but if I remove them I get weird output for some reason

Comment: How is `ft_strdup` implemented? What is this "checksum" you refer to as there is no code shown that does that? How is `get_next_line` called? What's the input file contents? Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as the exact input. Also, which exact line of code triggers the seg fault - a debugger can tell you that.

Comment: freeing "NULL" is a nop.  Telling us things get weird when actually freeing the memory associated with `l` means that the memroy around `l` has probably been compromised.  C is not a great language for string manipulations :)

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) use meaningful names.  Single char names, like `L` are meaningless even in the current context.

Comment: The posted code does not compile! The result of compiling is lots of `error` and `warning` messages. The posted code cannot be linked/run as it does not compile AND does not contain a `main()` function.

Comment: OT: regarding: `s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  suggest removing the cast.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  suggest removing that expression.  3) regarding: `buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (BUFFER_SIZE + 1));` the macro `BUFFER_SIZE` is not defined

Comment: regarding: `l = (!l) ? ft_strdup("") : l;`  what are you expecting this to perform?t

Comment: regarding: `while ((nbytes = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)` and `size_t      nbytes;`  The function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `size_t`

Comment: regarding: `static char *l;` and `l = (!l) ? ft_strdup("") : l;`   The variable `l` contains what ever trash is on the stack where the variable is declared.  So this is using an uninitialized local variable as a source.  This is undefined behavior.

Comment: this function; `get_next_line()` is never called anywhere in the posted code!

Comment: this function: `strlcat()` is not defined anywhere in the posted code

Comment: regarding: `temp = malloc(leng + 1);
        strlcat(temp, l, strlen(temp) + (leng - strlen(aux)) + 1);`  The buffer `temp`  is not initialized so calling `strlen()` on that buffer is undefined behavior.  trying to 'cat' more data into `temp` than the size of `temp` results in a buffer overflow which results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @user3629249 I've made changes based on your comments. strlcat() is included in the <string.h> library

Comment: Just simplify the code, and the error will magically disappear.

Comment: @user3629249: Note that `l` is declared `static`!  So it is not on the stack at all.  It is guaranteed to be initialized to NULL at the beginning of the program, and to keep its value between calls to the function.  So that code would not be undefined behavior.  (However, it no longer appears in the current version of the program, so I guess it's moot.)

Comment: @NateEldredge sorry, I have only modified the name of the variable `l` by `stc_line` since the commentary of partner asked me to put his name according to his function. Independently, the variable works as you have commented.

Answer (score 2):

```
temp = malloc(leng + 1);
strlcat(temp, l, strlen(temp) + (leng - strlen(aux)) + 1);
```

This is clearly wrong.  The memory allocated by `malloc` contains garbage, so calling `strlen` on it makes no sense, and trying to use `strlcat` to append to it will break horribly.  For instance, it is likely that the space you allocated doesn't contain a trailing nul byte, in which case `strlen(temp)` will return a number potentially much larger than `leng+1`, and `strlcat` may therefore write beyond the memory allocated.  Or, `strlen(temp)` may simply segfault.

(I found this using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/), and then noticed that user3629249 also noticed the bug in a comment.  I strongly recommend that you learn to use valgrind or a similar tool before proceeding any further with C.)

I cannot tell from your code what this function is supposed to do; it has an uninformative name and no comments.  But I think you should first specify carefully its intended behavior, and then rewrite it.

As another note, you have a serious memory leak in `main` in the `argc == 1` case:

```
        while ((ret = get_next_line(0, &buff)) > 0)
            printf("[Return: %d] Line #%d: %s\n", ret, ++line, buff);
        /* ... */
        free(buff);
```

Additional space is allocated for every line, and never freed.  Only the last one is freed (outside the loop).  When I ran your program, it used several gigabytes of memory for a modestly sized input file.

There are several other memory leaks in `get_next_line` where you use `strdup` to allocate strings that you never free.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I managed to solve the problem